# Why is the identity map of the circle not straight-line homotopic to a constant map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

According to the book 'Introduction to Topology. Pure and Applied' by C Adams & R Franzosa :

> $\boldsymbol{\sf THEOREM\ 9.9.}$ *A circle function $f : S^1 \rightarrow  S^1$ has degree $0$ if and only if $f$ extends to a continuous function on the disk $D$ (that is, if and only if there exists a continuous function $F : D \rightarrow  S^1$ such that $F (x) = f (x)$ for all $x\in S^1$).*

I read the proof and it seems cool! But, the contradiction of the theorem itself is that : If $f$ is the identity function, i.e. if $f (\theta) = \theta$ (degree $1$), it still is extendable on the Disk and a straight-line homotopy $F(\theta, t) = (1-t) f (\theta)$ deforms $f (\theta)$ to a constant map which has degree $0$. Contradiction?

PS - Please let me know to add the proof below if it's necessary but I think the proof is irrelevant.

> ***Proof.*** Throughout the proof, we represent the points in the disk with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.
>
> $\quad$ First, assume that $f$ extends to a continuous function $F:D\to S^1$. Define a function $G:S^1\times I\to S^1$ by $G(\theta,t)=F(t,\theta)$. Since $F$ is continuous, so is $G$. Therefore $G$ is homotopy between the circle functions $G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}$ and $G|_{S^1\times\{1\}}$, implying that these functions have the same degree. The function $G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}$ is given by $$G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}(\theta)=G(\theta,0)=F(0,\theta)=F(0,0).$$ It follows that $G|_{S^1\times\{0\}}$ is a constant function and therefore has degree $0$. Thus, $G|_{S^1\times\{1\}}$ also has degree $0$. It is straightforward to see that $G|_{S^1\times\{1\}}$ is equal to $f$, implying that $f$ has degree $0$, as desired.
>
> $\quad$ Now assume that $f$ has degree $0$. Therefore there exists a homotopy $G:S^1\times I\to S^1$ such that $G(\theta,0)=c_0(\theta)$ and $G(\theta,1)=f(\theta)$, where $c_0:S^1\to S^1$ is the constant function sending each point $\theta\in S^1$ to the point $0\in S^1$. Define $F:D\to S^1$ by $F(r,\theta)=G(\theta,r)$. Since $G(\theta,r)$ is constant in $\theta$ when $r=0$, it follows that $F$ is well defined at $r=0$ and therefore is defined as a function on $D$. Furthermore, $G$ being continuous implies that $F$ is  as well. Finally, $F(1,\theta)=G(\theta,1)=f(\theta)$, implying that $F$ is an extension of $f$. $\tag*{${\blacksquare}{}$}$

Comment: The identity is not extendable to the disc - that would be the same as saying that $D$ retracts onto its boundary, which is false.

Comment: @SamCappleman-Lynes Yes I know that! But what's the wrong point with exactly my suggested contradiction? Not other facts, but the wrong on exactly my written-above statement.

Comment: @L.G. If I'm reading right, your question is really, "Why is the identity map of the circle not straight-line homotopic to a constant map?" For the purposes of the question, Theorem 9.9 is irrelevant. If you edit the question title and body to clarify, I think your question will be more useful to posterity. :)

Comment: What exactly is $(1-t)f(\theta)$? How do you multiply a number with an element of $S^1$?

Comment: If you mean that $S^1$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then your $F$ maps $S^1 \times I$ to a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, not to $S^1$ as it should.

Comment: @DanShved - as in the proof, it's $S^1\times I \rightarrow S^1$ not $S^1\times I \rightarrow D$.

Comment: @L.G. How is $(1-t)f(\theta)$ an element of $S^1$? It is either undefined or doesn't belong to $S^1$, depending on your precise definition of $S^1$.

Comment: @DanShved - I understand now what you say. Two things: G: S1×I→S1 so is wrong in the proof, and I didn't find solution to my original question! (I edited the title of OP). Thanks. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - that's exactly what I meant to ask (and thanks), and I got it by reading the theorem 9.9. I edited the title, I hope I can get find an answer! :)

Comment: @MathsIsFun - Thanks a lot for your help. I have to think about the proof and your answer, etc more to be convinced, though. :)

Comment: As far as I can see, you interpreted "extends to the disk" as meaning "extends to a map $D\to D$", whereas the intended meaning, explained in parentheses in the text you quoted) is "extends to a map $D\to S^1$."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ were homotopic to a constant map, you would need the homotopy to stay within $\mathbb{S}^1$, $$F:\mathbb{S}^1\times I \to \mathbb{S}^1$$ But it doesn't: $$|(1-t)f(\theta)|=|1-t||f(\theta)|=|1-t|\neq 1, \text{ for every } t\neq 0.$$

So you have the identity on the disk homotopic to a constant (what you have proven via $F:D\times I \to D$), but the identity on the sphere cannot be homotopic to a constant via your homotopy via restriction of your homotopy (because $F(\mathbb{S}^1\times I)\nsubseteq \mathbb{S}^1$, as we have shown above).

EDIT: It is true that $F:D\times I \to D$ given by $F(x,t)=tx_0+(1-t)x$ is a straightline homotopy between the identity function $id:D\to D$ and the constant any point $x_0$ of the disk, $c:D\to D$, $c: x\mapsto x_0$. Just check the definition for this homotopy.

Your confusion arises because the degree of a map is defined for maps $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{S}^n$. It is precisely the integer $d$ such that $H_n(f):H_n(\mathbb{S}^n)\to H_n(\mathbb{S}^n)$ is given by $H_n(f)[x]=d[x]$, where $[x]$ is a fixed generator for $H_n(\mathbb{S}^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, being your case $n=1$. Sorry for the mess.

Also, note that there is no contradiction in the theorem because $G$ is being restricted to $\mathbb{S}^1\times \{0\}$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$ and therefore it makes sense to talk about degree.

Comment: I added the proof saying that homotopy is from $S^1\times I$ to $S^1$; so homotopy doesn't stay within $S^1$! I would appreciate clear explanation, I am new to the subject. :)

Comment: Assume $F:\mathbb{S}^1\times I\to \mathbb{S}^1$ is your homotopy, $F(\theta,t)=(1-t)f(\theta)$. Then, as $f:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$, it must happen that $|f(\theta)|=1$ for every $\theta$. But, for say, $t=1/2$ in your homotopy, you have $|F(\theta,1/2)|=|1/2||f(\theta)|=1/2\neq 1$, so you cannot have the image to be contained in $\mathbb{S}^1$, as there is a point in the domain (namely, $(\theta,1/2)$) such that the norm of its image is smaller than 1. So $F(\mathbb{S}^1\times I) \nsubseteq \mathbb{S}^1$

Comment: I understand now what you say. Two things: G: S1×I→S1 so is wrong in the proof, and I didn't find solution to my original question! (I edited the title of OP). Thanks. :)

Comment: I thought your question was to find what was wrong with the homotopy you gave. I don't understand your question now. It is true that the identity on the disc is homotopic to any constant function on the disc by a straight line.

Comment: *'the identity on the disc is homotopic to any constant function on the disc by a straight line'*: But the identity has degree 1, since it is $f(\theta)=1 \theta$ (degree $n$ means $c_n(\theta)=n\theta$ but constant map has degree 0. That's contradiction is all what I want to understand. Thank you

Comment: Ah!! I got it now! Sorry, but the degree is only defined for maps of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ into itself. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping , it doesn't make sense to consider the degree for a function defined on the disk in this context (at least, in principle!).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that the mentioned proof has to be revised.